# XCode 5 Organizer's provisioning Tab

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am not able to find out provisioning tab to delete old .mobileprovision files as it was in XCode 4.x. I want to add new one but want to be sure that the old files have been deleted. Could anyone please tell me the directory path or any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provisioning profiles and Developer identities are now under the Account tab in preferences. You can edit the provisioning profiles associated to your Apple ID by clicking on the "View Details..." button.

Comment: Account tab is blank. There is no "View Details" button.

Comment: Got it. I was needed to tap on "Add Apple ID". Once I entered my details I got "View Details" button, where all the provisioning files are loaded. Thanks @Tomas

Comment: I think we don't need to delete old provisioning files anymore as we are directly accessing the updated files from developer account. Right? If yes then Apple made it easy to manage.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't delete them manually anymore. The entire process of managing provisioning profiles has been greatly simplified. Xcode 5 does a great job in fixing most of the issues automatically